# How can I change a string to make it URL friendly?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL Slugify alrogithm in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920744/url-slugify-alrogithm-in-c)

I would like to convert a string like this:

```
Testing this on-the-test-forum (please/remove) if possible. test: test, "abc"
```

To a string like this:

```
testing-this-on-the-test-forum-please-remove-if-possible-test-test-abc
```

Does anyone have any ideas on the simplest type of function that I could use for this. What I am looking for is something very simple as I need to use this function later within LINQ.

Comment: This is called a [slug](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+slug).

Comment: This is starting to look a lot more complicated than I expected :-(

Comment: @Marife just take the code from the duplicate and you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest approach would seem to be identifying the characters that you do want in the returned string and code it based on these. So, in pseudocode:

```
newstring = "";

foreach(character in newstring.tolower)
    if(character in allowedcharacters)
        newstring+=character;
    else
        newstring+="-";

return newstring.replace("--","-");
```

That should be a start for you.