# How to handle Japanese names in url?

Tags: c#, seo, slug

The method described here [URL Slugify algorithm in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920744/340760) returns `""` for the input `ブルノ`.

Is it ok to include Japanese characters in URLs or does it hurt SEO? Will Google/Bing display as `ブルノ` or `%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8E`?

What should I do for the user `アウロン`?

1. /user/1/auron (different field to set the name in url)
2. /user/1/アウロン (set his displayname in url)

`ja.wikipedia.org` [does use Japanese characters in the URL](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=user%20%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3&btnG=Search&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%E6%B0%B4%20site:ja.wikipedia.org&oq=%E6%B0%B4%20site:ja.wikipedia.org&gs_l=serp.3...13799.15265.5.17171.5.5.0.0.0.3.245.1212.2-5.5.0.les;..0.0...1c.1j4.TI6tg_s14E8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8b48cc23068efa9f&biw=1538&bih=839), so can I just assume it is safe? Or does it need something else?

Comment: Do not use slugs for non-Latin characters, use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode. Actually, do not use slugs for any URLs ever.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use the second choice `2./user/1/アウロン.`

The reason is, if I do not have the japanses language installed on my machine (I use Windows 7) and you send me a link like www.abc.com/user/1/アウロン it will display a link to [www.abc.com/user/1/](http://www.abc.com/user/1/) instead of [www.abc.com/user/1/アウロン](http://www.abc.com/user/1/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3).

I noticed this behavior when I sent a link that contains Thai characters to my coworkers on Skype. It linked to incorrect link like what I said in the previous paragraph.